# Is there any syntax error in my sentence?

Tags: subordinate-clauses, dependent-clause

I am not sure whether the following sentence is syntax correct or not.

> It's have been nearly one month that I didn't receive any task from my
>   leader.

I know there is another sentence that can express the same meaning.

> It's have been nearly one month since I received the last task from my leader.

But I want to stress the time by place the time words in the beginning of my sentence.

If there is no error in

> It's have been nearly one month that I didn't receive any task from my
>   leader.

, can anyone help me figure out the grammar usage of the clause

> that I didn't receive any task from my leader.

I know it's not a relative clause, but what type clause is it?
Any explanation is grateful.

Comment: 'It's been nearly a month since I received the last task from my leader.' But this question is not what we are looking for on ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry. Where should I go to ask this question?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You mean ELU is not the place the OP is looking for, rather?

Comment: The place to go is ELL. (English Language Learners).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you say:

It's been nearly a month since I received a task from my leader.

Or :

I haven't received a task from my leader for/in nearly a month.

Or:

The last task I received from my leader was nearly a month ago.